# Keyboard shortcut to switch to result tab in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Does anyone know if there is any shortcut to switch tabs (editot,result, messages) in SQL Management Studio?
In my configuration i have enalbled option "Disply result in separate tab"

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if you could use Ctrl+1/2/3 to jump between tabs inside a document, or something like that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please use F6 to toggle between different tabs of SSMS.

Thanks,
Sree